# Extracting the elements of a JsonB dictionary in PostgreSQL 12

Tags: json, postgresql, dictionary, jsonb

I have looked at similar questions, but I can't find how to go from storing dictionaries in:

Table A: *id int, data jsonb*

```
For example:

id = 1
data = {"Key1": 1, "Key2": "a2", "Key3": [3, 4]}
```

to Table B: *id int, key text, payload jsonb*

```
Using the same example as above, I would get the 3 records:

id  Key    payload
--------------------
1   Key1        1
1   Key2   "a2"
1   Key3   [3, 4]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb_each()`:

```
insert into table_b
select id, key, payload
  from table_a
 cross join lateral jsonb_each(data) as e(key, payload);
```

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I needed. Great answer.